# Xml filing issue?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am entring data in xml file but it is not going in a proper way because of which when i retrieve my data it only retrieve some part of data.

Can u help me that how can i enter data, retrieve whole data and to compare the specific data i enter in text box.???

Here is my code:
This is for entring data.:

```
string curFile = @"D:\5 Semester\Project\VP Project\VP Project\bin\Debug\New Entry.xml";
            string s1 = textBox1.Text;
            string s2 = textBox2.Text;
            string s3 = comboBox3.Text;
            string s4 = comboBox1.Text;
            string s5 = comboBox2.Text;


        if (File.Exists(curFile) && curFile!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                var library = XElement.Load("New Entry.xml");
                library.Add(new XAttribute("FirstName",s1));
                library.Add(new XElement("First", new XAttribute("Name", s1)));
                library.Add(new XElement("Last", new XAttribute("Name", s2)));
                library.Add(new XElement("Profession", new XAttribute("Type", s3)));
                library.Add(new XElement("Department", new XAttribute("Degree", s4)));
                library.Add(new XElement("Semester", new XAttribute("No", s5)));
                library.Save("New Entry.xml");
                MessageBox.Show("Data Appended!");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
        else if (!(File.Exists(curFile)))
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("New Entry.xml"))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("New_Entry");
                writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", s1);
                writer.WriteElementString("LastName", s2);
                writer.WriteElementString("Profession", s3);
                writer.WriteElementString("Department", s4);
                writer.WriteElementString("Semester", s5);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
                writer.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("File Created!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Cannot be Created!");
        }
```

This is for retrieving data:

```
XPathNavigator nav;
        XPathDocument docNav;
        docNav = new XPathDocument(@"D:\5 Semester\Project\VP Project\VP Project\bin\Debug\New Entry.xml");
        nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
        nav.MoveToRoot();
        nav.MoveToFirstChild();
        do
        {
            //Find the first element.
            if (nav.NodeType == XPathNodeType.Element)
            {

                //Determine whether children exist.
                if (nav.HasChildren == true)
                {
                    //Move to the first child.
                    nav.MoveToFirstChild();

                    //Loop through all the children.
                    listBox1.Items.Add("All Record ");
                    do
                    {
                        //Display the data.
                        listBox1.Show();
                        listBox1.Items.Add(nav.Value);
                    }
                    while (nav.MoveToNext());
                }
            }
        }
        while (nav.MoveToNext());
    }
```

But it is not retrieving whole data.... And how can i compare the data which is stored in xml. The data i entered in textbox and xml file data if it matches than it displays that following data.

Answer (score -1):

first of all : if the XML file is in the same folder with your .exe app, then no need for full path, simply use ("file.xml");
for dealing with xml files the best and most easy way is going like this :
you will need to build a class so you can define your fields,properties and build your constructor..

```
        List<yourclass> data= new List<yourclass>();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("file.xml");
                    XmlNodeList list= doc["your root"].ChildNodes;
                    foreach (XmlNode node in list)
                    {
    //get all child nodes inner text
                        string[] info = { clt["info1"].InnerText, clt["info2"].InnerText, clt["info3"].InnerText, clt["info4"].InnerText, aslong as it is };
//ad all info to your class list
                        data.Add(new client(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4], info[5], info[6], info[7], info[8],info[9]));
                    }
                return data;
```

and for saving :

you will need to load the XML document as before ,then create your new nodes and fill them, then get the node you need to append in or create new node and append it to root node..

```
doc.Load("file.xml");
XmlNode any= doc.CreateElement("elementname");
any.InnerText = textsource.ToString();
targetnode.AppendChild(any);
rootnode.AppendChild(targetnode);
doc.Save("file.xml");
```

Comment: Please i am a beginner tell me the exact code for my code as i have told u. Tell me the exact syntax for the above code!!!

Comment: i am having error on doc and targetnode too. How to remove these errors.

Comment: @John .. well thanks for the -1, at least i tried to explain how to use OOP with XML files , that would save lots of time and lots of code lines .. what did you explain?!

Comment: i am having error on doc and targetnode how to overcome that error??

Comment: Since the OP is using LINK to XML, your suggestion to use `XmlDocument` doesn't make much sense. Feel free to post a solution which uses `XDocument`.